# examples of polyclic groups

Tags: group-theory

From the notes [Coarse diﬀerentiation and the geometry of
polycyclic groups](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~vogtmann/MSRI/Eskin.pdf), I found a theorem

> $\Gamma$ is polycyclic iff $\Gamma$ is a lattice in a solvable
>   unimodular lie group $G$ - **Mostow**

Then I started looking up definitions:

- What is an example of $\Gamma$ and $G$ ?

It is known that polycyclic groups are amenable.  How does one write down the averaging procedure?

---

My knowledge of infinite group is very limited:

- Wikipedia says [amenable groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group) have a $G$-invariant averaging procedure

  - for finite $G$ this leads to the character theory of finite groups
  - for $\mathbb{Z}$ the averaging procedure is pretty clear, such as $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N$
  - Wikipedia lists [solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group#Examples) groups as example of amenable groups
  - In search of an example of an infinite solvable group, I found that [polycyclic and supersolvable groups are solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group#Related_concepts).

These definitions are too abstract for me to follow-- I would like a "concrete" example of a polycyclic group.

It may not be so obvious abelian groups are amenable after all...

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12169/why-are-abelian-groups-amenable?rq=1

---

I am interested since I read a blog about amenable groups and I needed an example to try out.

Comment: 1) A polycyclic group *is* is a solvable unimodular Lie group, and is a lattice in itself. Do you mean connected or with finitely many components? 2) I can't guess the meaning of the sentence including "I will just say". 3) $SL_n(\mathbf{Z})$ is not polycyclic.

Comment: @YCor I can't find definitions or example of the notions of the theorem.  I would like to see an explicit example of a "solvable unimodular lie group" $G$ and a lattice $\Gamma$ in that group.

Comment: @YCor, re: your point (1): is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (which is certainly polycyclic) a Lie group? The definition I'm familiar with would say no, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @johnmangual, definitions of "polycyclic," "lattice," and "solvable unimodular Lie group" are easily found online; as for examples, Corollary 1 of the paper https://www.math.lsu.edu/~pdani/conferences/goa2010/SpeakerNotes/venkataramana.pdf states that any locally compact topological group which admits a lattice is unimodular, so that should help you get lots of examples.

Comment: @noah s: So you don't consider zero-dimensional manifolds to be manifolds?

Comment: Whoops, good point. I have a bad habit of assuming $n>0$ sometimes. :)

Comment: @NoahS So $U(n)$ is locally compact topological group so it is "unimodular".  Then the lattice would be $SO(n,\mathbb{Z})$ or some other arithemtic group - as in these [notes](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~remy/smf_sec_18_04.pdf).  However, $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is not polycyclic - so I am still not understanding.

Comment: Is $U(n)$ solvable?

Comment: @NoahS I don't know, is it?  Google says upper triangular is sufficient.

Comment: Migrating, as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a solvable unimodular **(connected)** Lie group $G$, and a lattice $\Gamma$ in that group:

- $G$ is the semidirect product $\mathbb{R}^2 \rtimes \mathbb{R}$ with respect to the action of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by 
  $$t \mapsto \pmatrix{e^t & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t}}
  $$
  This Lie group is isomorphic (as a Lie group) to any semidirect product with respect to an action defined by
  $$t \mapsto M^t
  $$
  for which the generating matrix $M \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ has distinct real eigenvalues $\lambda>1$ and $\lambda^{-1} \in (0,1)$. For example one could use
  $$M = \pmatrix{2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1}
  $$
  Of course to define $M^t$ one first picks a matrix $P$ in the Lie algebra $sl(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $M=\exp(P)$, and then $M^t = \exp(tP)$.
- $\Gamma$ is the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ with respect to the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ defined using the above matrix $M$.